# How to Truncate String within Limited Characters including space

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to limit the number of characters in a string.

However when I try the following:

```
Truncate.TruncateString(_longString, 300);
```

I Still get spaces included beyond 300 characters.  Is there an alternative so that spaces are counted within the character limit?

```
public static string TruncateString (this string value, int maxChars)
{
    return value.Length <= maxChars ? value : value.SubString(0, maxChars) + "...";
}
```

Comment: The `Truncate` class is not part of the .NET framework. I'd recommend talking to whoever wrote the `TruncateString` method.

Comment: Could you show the code of TruncateString?

Comment: Why a custom class? _longString.Substring(0, 299).Trim() will do what you want.

Comment: Can somebody please explain me how `value.SubString(0, maxChars) + "..."` will end with spaces? And how can it be longer than `maxChars + 3` characters?

Comment: There are thousands of right examples of `Truncate` for a string. [(Example)](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/string/truncate) This one fails if the string has more than 300 chars in length because the string returned is 303 chars

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze I think the issue is that the op doesn't want spaces between the end of the strings of chars and the "..."

Comment: @N4TKD Ok, makes sense. But then the accepted answer doesn't work because in case of a long string `TruncateString` will return a string that ends with `...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the trailing spaces (and often you don't), you can always do this:

```
Truncate.TruncateString(_longstring, 300).Trim();
```

**Edit**

Although this answer was accepted as correct, the right way is actually to leave the `Trim()` out of the above statement and instead to put it here:

```
public static string TruncateString (this string value, int maxChars)
{
    value = value.trim();
    return value.Length <= maxChars ? value : value.SubString(0, maxChars).Trim() + "...";
}
```

Comment: This will trim the end white spaces before the custom class shortens it, so if the center of the string has a substring of white spaces he still will have the problem.

Comment: @ENC0D3D to make this work do the Trim() on the string after the custom class shortens it.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked! Hmm....Now if SO would give split points awards this would benefit both of you.

Comment: @ENC0D3D thanks but I really don't care about the points on these pages, the learning is fun in itself.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But in case of a long string `TruncateString` returns a string that ends with `...`, right? What will the call to `Trim()` do?

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze it returns the shortened string he is adding + "..." to it see his code sample.

Comment: @N4TKD Yeah, shorted string with `...` in the end. The question stays: what `Trim()` will trim?